# How to print value of a constant/macro while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

While debugging an iOS application, I know how to print values of objects using :

**print** "variable name"

**po**    "variable name"

**p**     "integer Variables"

I wanted to know how to print value of a constant while debugging in Xcode? 
Is there any command that prints value of a constant? Because, if I use the above commands, the Xcode returns an error saying

`error: use of undeclared identifier`

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "constant" is that `const int something = 123;` or `#define SOMETHING 123`?

Comment: No you can't.  Use `const int ...` or `typedef enum { ... } MyType;` instead of pre-processor constants.

Comment: So, I cannot print the value of the macro at runtime in Xcode?

Comment: No.  Using `enum` is better anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros (what you get when you #define something) are the domain of the language preprocessor.  They are expanded and the expanded value is used when compiling your code.

The debugger doesn't parse your source file, it works off of what's in the binary.  So no, you won't be able to view the value of #define macros in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but nowadays compiling with [`-g3`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) (GCC) or [`-fdebug-macro`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-fdebug-macro) (Clang) will generate debug information for such preprocessor macros.